# How to handle I18n::InvalidLocale from rescue_responses config in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, locale, rails-i18n

I am working on a rails app. And trying to handle all of custom and native exceptions using Rack's native way by adding these configs in application.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!('Exceptions::RecordNotFoundError' => :not_found, 'ActionController::RoutingError' => :not_found, 'I18n::InvalidLocale' => :not_found)
```

Note: `Exceptions::RecordNotFoundError` is a custom exception.

My website is not catching `I18n::InvalidLocale` exception. Am I doing anything wrong. I do not want to add rescue statement in my application controller to handle this exception.